# Enabling XSLl in PHP

Tags: php, xslt, php-extension

I have a server with php5 installed on it. I need to enable XSL on it. when I try `phpinfo();` I don't see anything related to XSL. I already have "libxslt" installed.

Is there a way through which I can upgrade my php installation to have xsl support?
I don't want to reinstall php.

I thought of adding `extension=xsl.so` to `php.ini` but I don't know if I have xsl.so there and where it is! but does that work?? if yes I have to figure out where xsl.so is or download it if that's possible.

Please help me because this is my first experience in a real working environment.

BTW: The server OS is Linux (a property distribution base on RPM).

UPDATE:

I tried the following method but still can't enable xsl or see any difference in `phpinfo()`:

1- decompress the php source code and `cd` to the directory of the extenstion i.e. `cd /path/to/php/ext/xsl`

2- `phpize`

3- `./configure`

4- `make`

5- then move the xsl.so to the extension_dir

6- restart apache

I found this on many forums and blogs online but I don't know why it didn't work with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally could enable XSL without recompiling the whole PHP, using `phpize` command:

[How to enable php extension using `phpize`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200994/how-to-enable-php-extension-using-phpize)

the most important thing is enabling `DOM` extension **before** compiling the `XSL` extension and enabling it..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP5 should include the xsl extension by default. Your particular php installation may need to be recompiled with the argument --with-xls[=DIR], where DIR is the directory where your libxslt is installed.

When I set this up for myself, I founf this article to be helpful: http://flex.sys-con.com/node/200299?page=0,3

Comment: I didn't install php nor libxslt myself so I don't know where they are they and I can't remove php because there are other web applications that are running and I don't want to lose or affect them.