# How to enable php extension using `phpize`?

Tags: php, php-extension

I tried these steps on different extensions but I don't know why that doesn't work. Shouldn't I see a change in `phpinfo()` output after that?

The steps:

1. Decompress the php source code and change directory to `ext/ext_name`
2. `phpize`
3. `configure`
4. `make`
5. move manually the "ext_name.so" file from "../.lib" directory to "extension_dir" specified in "php.ini" file. (or do `make install` )
6. restart web service

Is there something missing? I need to enable a certain extension in php and there's no way to recompile the whole php version..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `.so` is properly compiled etc, and it's in your extension dir, then you need to add the following line also:

```
extension=NAME.so
```

This will force the loading. At this point, provided there is actually something to display, it will show in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I did that, but the only result I got is a warning `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry in Unknown on line 0` :(

Comment: This means that the module you just compiled is dependent on the PHP DOM module, you also need to enable this (before you enable `xsl.so`). Are you building the module for the right version of PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by "the right version of PHP?" I downloaded php source with the same version as the one already installed.. I tried the same steps with DOM but again I saw no changes in phpinfo() so I can't tell if DOM was enabled or not :(

Comment: Thank you for your help, I re-did the process again after I deleted all the previous generated files.. FIRST: Do the steps for `dom` extension including adding `extension=dom.so` in `php.ini` file, SECOND: Do the steps for `xsl` extension and add `extension=xsl.so` after the previous line.. restart httpd.. `phpinfo()` says that xsl in enabled.. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. Sorry btw, I didn't see your first reply 15 hours ago!