# Installing PHP on a Mac OS that already has PHP?

Tags: php, macos, postgresql

I need to install a version of PHP that has been compiled to work with Postgres, unlike the default version that came with my Mac Leopard system.   How can I do this without somehow disabling the httpd.conf and php.ini files or confusing the system due to having so many of them?

Comment: You could just compile the postgres module and load it into your existing PHP.

Comment: See: [How to enable php extension using `phpize`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200994/how-to-enable-php-extension-using-phpize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used homebrew to do this:

```
brew install https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/raw/master/duplicates/php.rb --with-mysql --with-intl --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --enable-cli --enable-mbregex --with-pgsql
```

this shouldn't replace the existing php.ini file, but if you want to be careful, you can make a copy first. it doesn't affect httpd.conf

[more detailed explanation](http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-53-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: using brew worked for me. i had to disable the native apache server in order to use my brewed version, but no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts creates an entirely separate install tree for its packages:

```
sudo port install php5-postgresql
```

will install everything you need.  Your php.ini, for example, will be in /opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini.

Get MacPorts from here: [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)